# Access to a child element from info of eventClick from Fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I'm using fullcalendar.js in Jquery. I have a problem to get a child element from a HTMl element.

I call https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventClick which returns me **info**.

```
eventClick: function(info) {
           console.log(info.el);
           let $el = $.parseHTML(info.el);
           console.log($el);
           console.log(info.el.children('.tooltipster'));
```

So the fist console.log return me

```
    <a class="fc-time-grid-event fc-event fc-start fc-end fc-draggable fc-short" style="background-color: rgb(37, 126, 74); border-color: rgb(37, 126, 74); top: 356px; bottom: -382px; z-index: 1; left: 0%; right: 0%;">
      <div class="fc-content tooltipster tooltipstered" data-tooltip-content="#tooltip_content0">
         <div class="fc-time" data-start="14:00" data-full="14:00 - 14:30">
           <span>14:00 - 14:30</span>
         </div>
         <div class="fc-title">XXX</div>
      </div>
    </a>
```

The second one give me **null**

And the last One

> TypeError: info.el.children is not a function

What I want to do is to access my child element with ".tooltipstered" as a class in order to get is value of 'tooltip-content' attr.

Thank you

Comment: Do you want "#tooltip_content0" on eventClick?

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I want

Comment: Can you share some more code? May be HTML and JS?

Comment: Also, which version of fullcalendar you are using?

Comment: Thank you for you time but I've just found a solution

Comment: Okay. great!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to cover **info.el** with a jQuery tag like this **$(info.el)**

```
 eventClick: function(info) {
           console.log(info.el);
           let $el = $(info.el);
           console.log($el);
           console.log($el.children('.tooltipster'));
```